# Adjust minimum height of body floater to navigation floater that contains more than one div

Tags: html, css

Code and [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjvpjQ):

```
.wrapper1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper2 {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
.content1 {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.content2 {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.content2, .wrapper2 {
    margin-bottom: -500em;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
}
.wrapper3 {
    clear: both;
}

<div class="wrapper1">

<div class="wrapper2">
<div class="content1">
text
</div>
<div class="content1">
text
</div>
</div>

<div class="content2">
text
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper3"></div>
```

I want to make it so content2 is at minimum the same height as wrapper2, whose height changes with content. Tried adding and subtracting padding and margin but it ended up with content2 stretching to the bottom of wrapper1. I want content2 to end at the bottom of the second content1 box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` to do this. By default, children of the flex parent will display in a row and `stretch` to fill the height of the parent.

```css
.wrapper1 {
 width: 700px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper2 {
 width: 150px;
}
.content1 {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
}
.content2 {
 width: 500px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
<div class="wrapper2">
<div class="content1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duo magna persius an.
</div>
<div class="content1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duo magna persius an.
</div>
</div>
<div class="content2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duo magna persius an. Cu adhuc iusto vel, sed ei vidit inciderint. Mel at duis quidam incorrupte, autem omnium ne mei. Ferri iudicabit et eos. Mei ex detraxit atomorum evertitur.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!